# python csv reader not handling quotes

Tags: python, csv

I have a file i wish to parse using a CSV reader, it has 12 rows but some of the columns contain quotes and to make things more complicated also commas and single quotes and new lines, the trouble is the csv reader does not handle the quotes correctly, the quotes within quotes are treated as a separate entity, here is a small sample of what I am dealing with.

```
ptr = open("myfile")
text = ptr.read()
ptr.close() 

for l in  csv.reader(text, quotechar='"', delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
    print l
```

the file contains:

```
"0","11/21/2013","NEWYORK","USA
 Atlantic ","the person replied \"this quote\" to which i was shocked,
this came as an utter surprise"

"1","10/18/2013","London","UK","please note the message \"next quote\" 
is invalid"

"2","08/11/2014","Paris","France",
"the region is in a very important geo strategic importance"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set escapechar in your reader:

```
csv.reader(..., escapechar='\\')
```

which by default is `None` (don't know why).

The second thing is that you initialize the reader incorrectly. You don't pass a string to reader, but a stream:

```
with open("myfile") as fo:
    reader = csv.reader(
        fo,
        quotechar='"',
        delimiter=',',
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
        skipinitialspace=True,
        escapechar='\\'
    )

    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: tried it, does not work,  every char after the new line is treated as separate entity : ['the person replied \n']
['t']
['h']
['i']
['s']
['']
['q']
['u']
['o']
['t']
['e']
['\n"']

Comment: @godzilla That's because you initialize the reader incorrectly. See my update.

Comment: omg, i have been playing with regex's to fix this problem and going mad, these few lines seem to have fixed the problem!!! Thank you

Comment: @godzilla is there a blank line present in-between the rows?

Answer (score 1):

Through re module.

```
import re
import csv
with open('file') as f:
    m = re.split(r'\n\n+', f.read())
    for line in m:
        print(re.findall(r'(?<!\\)"(?:\\"|[^"])*(?<!\\)"', line))
```

**Output:**

```
['"0"', '"11/21/2013"', '"NEWYORK"', '"USA\n Atlantic "', '"the person replied \\"this quote\\" to which i was shocked,\nthis came as an utter surprise"']
['"1"', '"10/18/2013"', '"London"', '"UK"', '"please note the message \\"next quote\\" \nis invalid"']
['"2"', '"08/11/2014"', '"Paris"', '"France"', '"the region is in a very important geo strategic importance"']
```

Comment: I am very new to regex's is there any documentation you can point me to which can help me decipher regex's?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ good site which covers all the regex flavors. And the best online regex tester site is https://regex101.com.

Comment: sorry can you please explain to me what (?:\\"|[^"]) in the regex does? I know it is a non matching and checks there are no quotes in between a quote...

Comment: ok, at first it checks each character before matching ie, it checks for the characters following `"` is escaped double quotes `\\"`. If there is any escaped quotes, it would match greedily at first. If the following character is not escaped quote, then the first condition fails and the control transfers to the next pattern ie, `[^"]` which checks for not of double quotes. If the condition is true then only it matches the corresponding character. If the match is fails, it immediately stops the matching. `*` after the non-capturing group repeats the above mentioned token zero or more times.